# HDP 2.6.1.0 - Error Finalizing HDP upgrade Failed on: Save Cluster State

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I'm trying to upgrade from hdp-2.4.0 to hdp-2.6.1
Updated ambari to 2.5 and all went ok, all services are green and all service checks run smoothly .
When I do the express upgrade to hdp-2.6.1 it gives error in the last part .
I've followed this [article](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/50014/error-finalizing-hdp-upgrade-failed-on-save-cluste.html?childToView=131057#answer-131057) but when I restart the server it gives this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adAev.jpg)

Is there any workaround for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some hints about the failure inside the log "/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server-check-database.log". Or at least post it here, otherwise the question sounds like "something is going wrong".

Try stating your server as following:

```
ambari-server start --skip-database-check
```

That would effectively bypass sanity checks as they are not always accurate.

Also, you may try your luck with

```
ambari-server start --auto-fix-database
```

But make sure to backup your database before that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - both on the upgrade direction from 2.5.0.0 to 2.6.2 and on the downgrade back to 2.5.0.0. Tried lots of stuff both via ambari-server and database surgery and eventually what did the trick was to nullify the reference to upgrade (downgrade) in the clusters table followed by ambari-server restart

psql -U ambari ambari

default password is bigdata

ambari=> select * from clusters;

cluster_id | resource_id | cluster_info | cluster_name | provisioning_state | s
ecurity_type | desired_cluster_state | desired_stack_id | upgrade_id
------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--
-------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------
          2 |           4 |              | myclus       | INSTALLED          | N
ONE          |                       |               51 |         52
(1 row)

ambari=> update clusters set upgrade_id = null where cluster_id = 2;
UPDATE 1

ambari=> select * from clusters;
 cluster_id | resource_id | cluster_info | cluster_name | provisioning_state | s
ecurity_type | desired_cluster_state | desired_stack_id | upgrade_id
------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--
-------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------
          2 |           4 |              | myclus       | INSTALLED          | N
ONE          |                       |               51 |
(1 row)